# How to export something after some fetch()

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class ProjectStore {
  constructor(projects: IProjectStrict[]) {
    this.projects = projects;
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  projects: IProjectStrict[];
}

export const ProjectStoreInstance = new ProjectStore(projects);
```

But the `projects`, which I pass into constructor - is a result of API call. I can neither use `export` in async IIFE:

```
(async () => {
  await fetchProjectList(url);
  export const ProjectStoreInstance = new ProjectStore(projects);
})();
```

nor use an `await` right in the constructor

```
export const ProjectStoreInstance = new ProjectStore(await fetchProjectList(url));
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use top-level `await` since Typescript v3.8 ([source](https://byrayray.dev/posts/2020-06-22-typescripts-new-top-level-await)), something like [in this ts playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgAoCcD2ArApqALgZWykhnAN7BxygoB202SArjoQBQAOqmO0AXHAJLJ0WPPQCWOANoBdAJSlyFONgAWY6ADoOw7nAC8cbV2zQA3IooB6S3AC2kANYYAggwIB5AEbQMSAG6QnuAYLKrqsuYUAL4gFEYivAJCxvhIEtgy5jFgNHRwDEjg%20nAA5DAAJiXmVLTYhoTGADLq2HyCnCKp6TLFkADukGJ1AGYY2KAqySLNdCwF4BHAGAAebIR1NXlTOPiEGPy1kNSgxAbUGH2IHTsEROwN0y2LwGLU2L7DkCdJ16JpOAoKJA%20HQ0tQAOZZEDDBjHbBiGhwUbjSa-GbYOaFEHiCGyPhCWzqDAAHnaOj%203WkAD5AXAiNgCtQ4OdLgSiaTthSpNSWERoChwH5TjS%20QKhSwZLJFlEgA).

```
class ProjectStore {
  constructor(projects: IProjectStrict[]) {
    this.projects = projects;
    // makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  projects: IProjectStrict[];
}

const url = 'asd';
const porjectList: IProjectStrict[] = await fetchProjectList(url);
export const ProjectStoreInstance = new ProjectStore(porjectList);

interface IProjectStrict {
  a: string;
}

function fetchProjectList(url: string): Promise<IProjectStrict[]> {
  return new Promise<IProjectStrict[]>(resolve => resolve([]));
}
```